# Can't figure out how to run scene in godot

Tags: godot

I'm very new to godot and was following the step by step tutorial on the godot website. I have godot 3.1 .

I made a script node that says "hello world" and tried to run the scene like the tutorial said, but nothing appears. I'm not sure how to put the code into this question since godot has a workspace and stuff and isn't a text editor. It's very simple though, just the script node with the text value changed.

I've tried searching up this problem and other people seem to get some error message when their scene doesn't run, but I don't get any error. I get this on my output though:

** Debug Process Started **
OpenGL ES 3.0 Renderer: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620

I'd really appreciate any help to get the scene to run, I'm looking forward to learning to make games in godot. :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's start from scratch:

- 1) Scene -> New Scene
- 2) On your scene tab, create a `Node2D` as root (by clicking the plus + sign and selecting Node2D).
  [image: Scene with Node2D as root]
- 3) Create a new script by clicking 
  [image: Add script icon]

This will generate an empty script:

```
extends Node2D

# class member variables go here, for example:
# var a = 2
# var b = "textvar"

func _ready():
    # Called when the node is added to the scene for the first time.
    # Initialization here
    pass

#func _process(delta):
#   # Called every frame. Delta is time since last frame.
#   # Update game logic here.
#   pass
```

- 4) Save the scene. Now you have a scene with a root node and a script attached to its lifecycle.
- 5) Run the current scene by clicking [image] on the top-right.
- 6) A black window should appear. From now on, you have a scene you can run and a script where you can add your code.

For a complete introduction from zero, you can check out the tutorials from [KidsCanCode](http://kidscancode.org/blog/2017/02/godot_101_01/)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering but I'm still having some trouble. I have tried what you said in your answer as well as what the KidsCanCode website said on their website, but the scene doesn't run properly. When I press to run the scene, I can see on my taskbar that another window has opened, but when I click on that window it is completely invisible. There is not even that little bar on the top or anything. Do you think there is something wrong with my computer if it is doing this?

Comment: I downloaded godot on my friend's PC and it works perfect! There's probably something wrong with my laptop, then. I'll keep practicing on PC, the KidsCanCode tutorials are really nice and simple to follow. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to this and just had the same exact problem. The solutions posted above didn't work but the added note in the tutorial did when I tried it after. I'll paste here.

If this doesn’t immediately work and you have a hiDPI display on at least one of your monitors, **go to Project → Project Settings → Display → Window then enable Allow Hidpi under Dpi**

Answer (score 0):

Probably your graphics card has poor support for OpenGL 3. You could try and change to OpenGL 2 on Project settings > Rendering > Quality > Driver